Copilot feasibility with VS 2019
We need to use Github Copilot with Visual Studio 2019. Can anyone help us to understand if this is possible?
Thank You

According to GitHub Copilot Completions extension's description, you could not install it in vs2019.

GitHub Copilot requires Visual Studio 2022 17.5.5 or newer. For Visual
Studio 2022 version 17.4.4 to 17.5.4, use extension version 1.84.0.1.

You could find the above sentence about requirements from the following link:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilotvs
